# Can I register a new thumbnail size and have it be an option in "Add Media"?

Tags: images

I would like to have a smaller thumbnail - 50px X 50px.

Right now I have to add media 150px and reduce each one by drag and drop.

Can I add another option besides thumbnail, medium and full size to the "add media" in WordPress?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

You have to use wordpress [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) ([tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/series/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api--cms-624)) to add new options/fields into such pages.

Also add [add_image_size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) function to register new size so wordpress create new image file according to given size.

As per your requirement you need 50x50 so I added icon_size field only you can change this as per your requirement.

Happy coding!

**To show into media section**

```
add_action('admin_init', 'stack_initialize_theme_options');
function stack_initialize_theme_options() {

    add_settings_section(
        'media_settings_section',
        'Custom Image sizes',
        'stack_media_options_callback',
        'media'
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'icon_size',
        'Icon size',
        'stack_toggle_size_callback',
        'media',
        'media_settings_section'
    );

    register_setting(
        'media',
        'icon_size'
    );
}

function stack_media_options_callback() {
    echo '';
}

function stack_toggle_size_callback($args) {

     $size = get_option('icon_size') ? : 50;

     $html  = '<label for="icon_size">Width</label>';
     $html .= '<input name="icon_size" type="number" step="1" min="0" id="icon_size" value="'.$size.'" class="small-text">';

     echo $html;
}
```

---

**Register new image size**

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'icon_size', 50, 50, true );
}
```